# freeGLUT grid drawing not drawing fully at specific values

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, glut

I am trying to draw a 2 dimensional grid depending on a given gridSize given by the user (the grid is always a square). 
However, for some values of the grid, the top line and the right line of the grid do not draw. For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code here.

This is my code in my render method to draw the grid:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);

for (float i = -1.0f; i <= 1.0f; i += 2.0f/(gridSize)) {
    glVertex2f(i, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(i, -1.0f);

    glVertex2f(-1.0f, i);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, i);
}
glEnd();
```

gridSize is just the user input for the size of the grid. I divide by 2.0, since
I want my grid to have a constant width and height of 2.0x2.0.

Values like 10, 25, 100 all work fine,
but values such as 50 don't draw the top and left line, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYo0e.png)

It might be some dumb detail that i'm missing, but i just can't see anything wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer loop variable & calculate the floating-point position inside the loop:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for( unsigned int j = 0; j <= gridSize; ++j )
{
    const float i = -1.0f + ( j * 2.0f/(gridSize) );
    glVertex2f(i, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(i, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, i);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, i);
}
glEnd();
```

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -1.1, 1.1, -1.1, 1.1, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    const unsigned int gridSize = 50;
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for( unsigned int j = 0; j <= gridSize; ++j )
    {
        const float i = -1.0f + ( j * 2.0f/(gridSize) );
        glVertex2f(i, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(i, -1.0f);
        glVertex2f(-1.0f, i);
        glVertex2f(1.0f, i);
    }
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```